# pyresttest run all tests in directory

Tags: python, unit-testing, testcase, pyresttest

I have some testcase files of type `yaml` in a directory. Im using [pyresttest](https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest) to run them and test my app. I want to run all tests in the directory. I can write a script to do it but is there anyway run all testcases with `pyresttest` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of PyRestTest here: there is not a way to do this.

Besides a script, what you can do is [create a test file that imports other files](https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest#import-example) in the same directory and then run that.

This is the suggested way to create higher-level test suites that reuse shared test files.